# graphql appsync query with boolean filter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync

I have the need to query all incomplete projects, wherein upon completion a project will be given a status change (`Completed`) plus a boolean `isComplete==true`.

I'm working through AWS Appsync to test the queries before I hard-code them into my app, but this one doesn't seem to be effective. I want all projects where `isComplete==false` or `isComplete==null`: boolean logic doesn't work with the `input1` variable below (0 results).

````
{"__typename":{"S":"Project"},"addressLine1":{"S":"321 Faith Cir"},"city":{"S":"Perris"},"createdAt":{"S":"2019-03-05T01:01:39.513Z"},"currentOwner":{"S":"pgres52"},"dateRequired":{"S":"2019-03-13-07:00"},"id":{"S":"89a5-42ef7efef8fb"},"status":{"S":"Created"},"statusLastChangedAt":{"S":"2019-03-05T01:01:39.513Z"}}

{
  "input1":{
    "isComplete": {
      "ne": true
    }
  }
}

query listNonCompleteProjects($input1: ModelProjectFilterInput) {
  listProjects(filter: $input1, limit: 20) {
    items {
      id
      currentOwner
      addressLine1
      city
      dateRequired
      isComplete
      statusLastChangedAt
    }
    nextToken
  }
}```
````

Comment: Are you using the AWS Amplify codegen or are you authoring the resolvers yourself?

Comment: Hi @Aaron_H, I used the Amplify codegen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Partially helped with this post: [Prisma.io: How do I filter items with certain fields being null?](https://www.prisma.io/forum/t/how-do-i-filter-items-with-certain-fields-being-null/553/7)

I was able to get it to work with an additional parameter `status` (string):

```
query listNonCompleteProjects($input1: ModelProjectFilterInput) {
  listProjects(filter: $input1, limit: 20) {
    items {
      ...
    }
  }
}
  "input1":{
    "and": [
      {"status": {"notContains": "Complete"}},
      {"isComplete": {
        "ne": true
      }}
    ]
  },
```